# C++ Array unknown operation

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, operation

Im reading over some code on github trying to understand what its doing.

I came across this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < N/GROUP_SIZE; k++) {

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < GROUP_SIZE; j++) {
            tempB[i][j] = *(B+k*GROUP_SIZE+i*N+j);
        }
    }
```

B is a one dimensional array of size (N*N)
tempB is a two dimensional array of size [N][GROUP_SIZE]

Im quite unsure what this line does though:

```
tempB[i][j] = *(B+k*GROUP_SIZE+i*B_WIDTH+j);
```

Does it access only part of the array? 
I would try to google this question, but im not sure what to call the operation

Comment: Need the declaration of B.

Comment: Assuming GROUP_SIZE <= N, it seems to grab the values from B and create a (2d) submatrix that is tempB.

Comment: Yes, GROUP_SIZE <= N, but i dont understand how using the array B + (value) does something to grab the values instead of doing B[value]

Comment: i think it's just a coding habit.. because A[i] is same as *(A + i)

Comment: There's nothing especially C++-ey here. Probably should be retagged with [tag:C].

Comment: @Spencer If its compiled with a c++ compiler, its C++. I don't think retagging it with `c` is a good idea. I might be wrong as im not usually active in the c++ area of the page so if thats common practice, just ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

`temp[i][j] =` accesses one cell of a multi-dimensional array and places the value into it.

As for `*(B+k*GROUP_SIZE+i*B_WIDTH+j)`, here `B` is the name of an array, which is also a pointer to the first element of that array.

`*(B + a)` is equivalent to `B[a]`. `B + 1` would point to the second element of that array, and `B + 2` to the second element. [`*` operator dereferences the pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator), and returning value at that index.